# How to store a different data type into a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, types, linked-list

I got two classes Data and write:

```
public class Write {
    String temp = "test";
    public List<Data> testing(Data data)
    {
        data.setMessage(temp);
        List<Data> dataz = new LinkedList<>();
        dataz.add(data.getMessage());
        return dataz;
    }
}
```

```
public class Data {
    String message;
    public void setMessage(String message){ this.message  = message; }
    public String getMessage(){ return message; }


}
```

I want to store the value of message into my linked list dataz but I provide the type String and the data type Data is required.
How can I still add message into my LinkedList without changing the linked list to `List<String> dataz = new LinkedList<>();`?

Comment: you can't, as simple as that. change the `dataz` definition

Comment: Can I instead create a Data object which contains message?

Comment: *"Can I instead create a Data object which contains message?"* ... You already have that, that's what you pass as `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Added an object and a toString method in class Data:

```
    public Data(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String toString(){
         return message;
    }
```

Class Write changes:

```
        Data message1= new Data(temp);
        dataz.add(message1);
```

Now

```
        System.out.println(dataz);
```

prints out a String.

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways:

- use Data type for object something in .add(something)
- change generic type to String and still use .add(something.getMessage())
- change generic type to Object (or remove generic), but you must use casting (with instanceof type checking) later

If you want to use string (message) representation of Data object later instead of usage getMessage method, you could override toString method, and then first way is appropriate for you (but it seems like not very good way) usg smpl: System.out.println(data);

Comment: wish i read it earlier, thats kinda how i solved it. Thanks :)